# Variable might not have been initialized? Error

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app and it doesn't really works out at the moment. The app calculates how much calories you burned with walking the stairs. But when I want to round up the amount of calories it says Variable might not have been initialized. So I made the double kcal = 0 . But when I tested my app it just gave the number 0.0 as the calories I burned that day. Do you guys know how to resolve this problem?

Here is my code where I Declare the doubles:

```
double trap;
double kcal = 0;
double endkcal = Math.round( kcal * 100.0 ) / 100.0;
double keer;
double gewicht;
double nul = 0.13;
String eten = "Je kan nu Niks eten";
```

And here is the calculating code:

```
trap = Double.parseDouble(editText_trap.getText().toString());
gewicht = Double.parseDouble(editText_gewicht.getText().toString());
keer = gewicht * nul / 4;
kcal = keer * trap;
textView_kcal.setText(String.valueOf(endkcal) + "kcal");
```

Comment: "Here is my code where I Declare the doubles:" Are they local or member variables? Please show the code with sufficient context.

Comment: Nowhere in your code you've posted do you update `endkcal`. It will always be 0. Its value doesn't change when you change `kcal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `endkcal = Math.round( kcal * 100.0 ) / 100.0;` after you calculate `kcal` to have correct calculation. Now it is normal to get 0.0 after calculation because `kcal` is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize all of your double variables when you have declared them like this:

```
double trap=0.0;
double kcal =0.0;
double endkcal = Math.round( kcal * 100.0 ) / 100.0;
double keer=0.0;
double gewicht=0.0;
double nul = 0.13;
```

Comment: When i do this i get the error that they don't get used.

Comment: where are you defining your variables?

Comment: @JeroenBoot You should learn the difference between an actual error and just a warning/suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your endkcal variable is only initialized (to 0.0) but never updated.